# How would I go about adding a 'recently played music' section to my website?

Tags: drupal, itunes

I have a personal website programmed in HTML and PHP with Drupal as a backend and I'd like to add a section to the website that displays the last song that I've played in itunes or a similar music program.

What would the best way be to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

if you use lastFM (http://www.last.fm) they have some widgets to use on you're personal website.

Comment: and there are already bindings between several media players and last.fm, right? :)

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but it'd be great if I could go about it without using a widget so it fits in better with the design of my website.

And, in the future, I'd like to possibly program statistics for most played (all time/30 days)

Comment: last.fm has an API where you could get the lastplayed songs... if you don't want to use last.fm you have to create something yourself I think.

Comment: Any ideas on how I would go about creating something myself? I would imagine VLC would probably be the easiest media player to work with.. but how would I get that into, say, a mysql database?

Comment: I found a website where someone seems to have accomplished something similar using perl that I'm looking into.. http://www.gregkurts.com/2010/02/09/getting-current-track-information-from-vlc-using-perl/
I'll play with it and update if I have any success.

Comment: I think the hardest part is to 'read' the played songs. if you have that part you could create a webservice, or a simple page where you send the data. In the webservice you save the data in a mysql database. If you have that you only have to read the data on you're website to display it.